# Validating the json files in a folder/sub folder through shell script

Tags: json, python-3.x, bash, shell, nested

find dir1 | grep .json | python -mjson.tool $1 > /dev/null

I am using the above command but this doesn't take the files as inputs. What should i do to check for all the json files in a folder and validate whether its a proper json.

Answer (score 2):

I found this a while back and have been using it:

```
for j in *.json; do python -mjson.tool "$j" > /dev/null || echo "INVALID $j" >&2; done;
```

I'm sure it compares similarly to `dasho-o`'s answer, but am including it as another option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 'xarg'.

The pipe find/grep will place the file names of the json file to STDIN. You need to create a command line with those file names. This is what xargs does:

```
find dir1 | grep .json | xargs -L1 python -mjson.tool > /dev/null
```

Side notes:

1. Since 'find' has filtering and execution predicates, more compact line can be created

```
find dir1 -name '*.json' -exec python -mjson.tool '{}' ';'
```

2. Also consider using 'jq' as light weight alternative to validating via python.